# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-intent

My apps currently will receive some data, but I just want to store the data somewhere and bring it to another screen. Here's what I do currently

Data class:

```
data class MTSnListItem(
    @SerializedName("skuCode") val skuCode: String?,
    @SerializedName("sn01") val sn01: String?,
    @SerializedName("sn02") val sn02: String?,
    @SerializedName("sn03") val sn03: String?,
    @SerializedName("sn04") val sn04: String?,
    @SerializedName("sn05") val sn05: String?
) : Parcelable
```

Receiving data activity:

```
//declare my arraylist
private var snList: ArrayList<MTSnListItem>? = null

//storing data in arraylist
if (responseSummary.has(SN_LIST) && !responseSummary[SN_LIST].isJsonNull){
val apiResponseSnList = responseSummary[SN_LIST].asJsonArray
val str = Util.getNullGson()?.toJson(apiResponseSnList)
val tempJsonList = Util.getNullGson()?.fromJson<ArrayList<MTSnListItem>>(
    str,
    object : TypeToken<List<JsonObject>>() {}.type
    )
snList = tempJsonList
}

//intent to pass data
val intent = MTEditActivity.startIntent(
    snList = snList
)
startActivityForResult(intent, MT_DETAIL_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Setting data activity

```
//declare my arraylist
private var snList: ArrayList<MTSnListItem>? = null

//intent put data
fun startIntent(
   snList: ArrayList<MTSnListItem>?
): Intent {
   val intent = Intent(context, MTEditActivity::class.java)
   intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ARG_SN_LIST, snList)
}

//intent get data
snList = intent?.getParcelableArrayListExtra<MTSnListItem>(ARG_SN_LIST)
```

The apps instantly crash when hitting

```
startActivityForResult(intent, MT_DETAIL_REQUEST_CODE)
```

and logcat shows the error 'Parcel: unable to marshal value'

My data might have 'null' pass through, not sure is that the problem, but I tried adding null to my data class, also not working

```
@SerializedName("sn01") val sn01: String? = null,
```

Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks!